# How do you import a CSV with subtables in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a .csv with different subtables which are named "# name:" and I'm trying to import this cleanly using pandas and/or csv. The subtables start in different positions in different files and the table names are in line with the header, looking like this:

```
# police_stations: loc_id, x_coord, y_coord, costk1, costk2, costk3, capk1, capk2, capk3,
h1, 0, 10, 100, 200, 300, 1, 2, 3,
h2, 10, 10, -10, 0, 150, 1, 3, 4,
# existing stations: loc_id, closing_income,
h2, 100,
# cities: loc_id, x_coord, y_coord,
c1, 5, 5,
c2, 25, 10,
# cities with minimum police station size 2: loc_id,
c1,
c3,
```

I tried this (and it works) but I'm looking for maybe a more elegant solution. I'm fairly new to this and it feels like there should be a way to import subtables more easily

```
df = pd.read_csv(full_path, header=None, index_col=0) #dataframe
pos_stations = df.index.get_loc("# police stations: loc_id")
pos_exstations = df.index.get_loc("# existing stations: loc_id")
stations = pd.read_csv(full_path, comment="#", index_col=False, nrows=pos_exstations-1, names = ["loc_id", "x_coord", "y_coord", "costk1", "costk2", "costk3", "capk1", "capk2", "capk3"])
```

Comment: wait, there are csv tables __in__ the csv table???

Comment: I guess so. Can I split this into multiple files easily?

Comment: Could you please post the output of printing your dataframe ```print(df)```. Thank you!